# Delete Local File When iCloud Drive File is Deleted

Tags: ios, xcode, delete-file, icloud-drive

I created an application that use `iCloud` to sync the devices. everything sync correctly except for deletion.

the situation is this.

I save a image file in device A and also save to its local document directory as well as my `iCloud` document directory.

when device B detect the change, it download the image file from `iCloud` and save to its local document directory.

the problem is following.

when device A delete the image file in its local document directory, it will also delete the image file in `iCloud` document directory.

However, device B will not delete its owe image file in its local directory.

I want the device B to delete its image file as well when the `iCloud` document directory.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Use [this](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/add-an-icloud-photo-gallery-to-your-app-with-mticloudphotogallery-library/) link for resolve your issue and there is one silly mistake on function name in the demo so you can resolve it in the given demo.

Comment: thank you Diken, but it doesn't looks like what I am looking for.

Comment: @CkwCfm, Have you tried to implement delete function from given link?

Comment: I have. in my case. when device A deletes the image, the device local image, icloud image will be deleted. but the local image in device B will not delete. I want to some how detect the deletion and device B delete its local image as well.